# Determining condition of coplanarity

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-analysis, plane-geometry

Determine the value of $\lambda$ such that the vectors $$5\vec{a}+6\vec{b}+7\vec{c},7\vec{a}+\lambda\vec{b}+9\vec{c},3\vec{a}+20\vec{b}+5\vec{c}$$ are coplanar given that $\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}$ are non coplanar.

For the vectors to be coplanar,there must exist scalars $x_1,x_2,x_3$ not all $0$ such that their linear combination is $0$. Then after rearranging,the condition we get is $$(5x_1+7x_2+3x_3)\vec{a}+(6x_1+\lambda x_2+20x_3)\vec{b}+(7x_1+9x_2+5x_3)\vec{c}=0$$
Since $\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}$ are non coplanar,hence each of the coefficients must be $0$.

But here,we are getting $3$ equations for $4$ variables(the fourth one being $\lambda$). So,how can $\lambda$ be determined? Can I assign any one of $x_1,x_2,x_3$ any value I like,for example can I make $x_1$ or $x_3$ $0$ or $1$ or any other number? I am really confused.

Comment: Notice that if $\vec x$ is a solution of your system of equations, then so is $\alpha\vec x$ for any scalar $\alpha$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I couldn't follow you. The system of equations all have scalers as unknown,so how can a vector,as you mentioned,be a solution? It will be very kind of you if you write an answer.

Comment: Do you know the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}5 &7  &3  \\6 &\lambda  & 20 \\7 & 9 & 5\end{bmatrix}$ associated with your system? It's easier to handle than a system (help : $>!-8$)

Comment: @StéphaneJaouen it will be very helpful if you kindly post an answer since that will be easy for me to understand.

Comment: a_i_r  just row reduce the matrix of coefficients. Done correctly, that will reveal the value of $\lambda$   that causes the matrix to have rank two rather than rank three.

Comment: @WillJagy could you please share your calculations? I am actually new to linear algebra,so it will be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's another approach which is imposing
$$\mathbf u\cdot(\mathbf v\wedge\mathbf w)=0,$$
where
$$\left\{\begin{align}
&\mathbf u=5\mathbf a+6\mathbf b+7\mathbf c\\
&\mathbf v=7\mathbf a+\lambda\mathbf b+9\mathbf c\\
&\mathbf w=3\mathbf a+20\mathbf b+5\mathbf c
\end{align}\right.$$
Let us now substitute and proceed:
$$\begin{align}
(5\mathbf a+6\mathbf b+7\mathbf c)\cdot((7\mathbf a+\lambda\mathbf b+9\mathbf c)\wedge(3\mathbf a+20\mathbf b+5\mathbf c))
&\overset{(1)}{=}(5\mathbf a+6\mathbf b+7\mathbf c)\cdot((140-3\lambda)\mathbf a\wedge\mathbf b+8\mathbf a\wedge\mathbf c+(5\lambda-180)\mathbf b\wedge\mathbf c)\\
&\overset{(2)}{=}7(140-3\lambda)\mathbf c\cdot(\mathbf a\wedge\mathbf b)+48\mathbf b\cdot(\mathbf a\wedge\mathbf c)+5(5\lambda-180)\mathbf a\cdot(\mathbf b\wedge\mathbf c)\\
&\overset{(3)}{=}[7(140-3\lambda)-48+5(5\lambda-180)]\underbrace{\mathbf a\cdot(\mathbf b\wedge\mathbf c)}_{\neq 0\, (4)}\overset{!}{=}0\\
&\iff 980-21\lambda-48+25\lambda-900=0\\
&\implies 32+4\lambda=0\implies \lambda=-8
\end{align}$$
Where at $(1)$ we used the fact that $\mathbf v_i\wedge\mathbf v_j=0$ if $i=j$, and $\mathbf v_i\wedge\mathbf v_j=-\mathbf v_j\wedge\mathbf v_i$; at $(2)$ that $\mathbf v_i\cdot(\mathbf v_j\wedge \mathbf v_k)=0$ if $i=j$ or $j=k$; at $(3)$ that every time you interchange places of two near vectors $\mathbf v_i\cdot(\mathbf v_j\wedge \mathbf v_k)$ changes its sign, and that at $(4)$ it is told that $\mathbf a$, $\mathbf b$, $\mathbf c$ aren't coplanar so $\mathbf a\cdot(\mathbf b\wedge\mathbf c)\neq 0$.

Answer (score 3):

The idea is any two nonparallel vectors can span out a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Let
$$\textbf{u}:=5⃗+6⃗+7⃗,\textbf{v}:=7⃗+⃗+9⃗,\textbf{w}:=3⃗+20⃗+5⃗$$
Then the coplanar condition implies **v** lies on the plane having **u** $\times$ **w** as the normal vector. This means you should solve $$\textbf{v}\cdot(\textbf{u}\times\textbf{w})=0$$
After computation you should get out something like $k(\textbf{a}\cdot(\textbf{b}\times\textbf{c}))=0$ for some constant $k$, but by the noncoplanar condition of **a**,**b** and **c**, this means $k=0$, so you can solve for lambda.

Answer (score 2):

If they are coplanar then

$\det\begin{bmatrix}5 &7  &3  \\6 &\lambda  & 20 \\7 & 9 & 5\end{bmatrix}=0$,

where the given matrix represents linear transformation in the basis with vectors $\bf{a,b,c}$.

Comment: Could you kindly tell me why this is the condition? It will be very helpful since I don't understand why that determinant should be $0$ for coplanarity.

Comment: Determinant determines a volume ( up to sign) of parallelepiped spanned on the vectors of the matrix, For coplanarity of vectors the volume must be $0$. See geometric meaning in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelepiped

Comment: But $<5,7,3>,<6,λ,20>,<7,9,5>$ aren′t the vectors that have to be coplanar.The ones which need to be are
$5a+6b+7c$ as I mentioned in the beginning of my post.

Comment: @a_i_r $5a+6b+7c$ is a single vector, being linear combination of vectors $a,b,c$

Comment: @a_i_r See also basic information about basis https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)

Answer (score 1):

Even if you don't know about matrix associated with your system, You can try to translate them into manipulations on your system :

$\begin{bmatrix}5 &7  &3  \\6 &\lambda  & 20 \\7 & 9 & 5\end{bmatrix}\overset{C_1'=7C_1\color{red}.C'_2=5C_2}\longleftrightarrow \begin{bmatrix}35 &35  &3  \\42 &5\lambda  & 20 \\49 & 45 & 5\end{bmatrix}\overset{C_1''=\frac37C_1'\color{red}.C''_2=C'_2-C'_1}\longleftrightarrow \begin{bmatrix}15 &0  &3  \\18 &5\lambda-42  & 20 \\21 & -4 & 5\end{bmatrix}\overset{C_3'=5C_3} \longleftrightarrow \begin{bmatrix}15 &0  &15 \\18 &5\lambda-42  & 100 \\21 & -4 & 25\end{bmatrix}\overset{C_3''=C''_1-C'_3} \longleftrightarrow \begin{bmatrix}15 &0  &0 \\18 &5\lambda-42  & -82 \\21 & -4 & -4\end{bmatrix}$
$\overset{R_2\leftrightarrow R_3} \longleftrightarrow \begin{bmatrix}15 &0  &0 \\21 & -4 & -4 \\18 &5\lambda-42  & -82 \end{bmatrix}\longleftrightarrow \begin{bmatrix}15 &0  &0 \\21 & -4 & 0\\18 &5\lambda-42  & 5\lambda+42 \end{bmatrix}$

Then  for $\boxed{\lambda=-8}$, $$5\vec{a}+6\vec{b}+7\vec{c},7\vec{a}+\lambda\vec{b}+9\vec{c},3\vec{a}+20\vec{b}+5\vec{c}$$ are coplanar.

---

Note : The dot "$\color{red}.$" above the arrows means "and"

Comment: Could you please share how you deduced $\lambda=-8$? And don't we need to form a lower triangular matrix to get the final form of matrix?

Comment: Do $\lambda=-8$ in the final matrix, you'll understand :)

Comment: But I don't understand one thing,how is it even possible to solve a system of $3$ equations with $4$ variables? Don't we need $n$ equations for $n$ variables?

Comment: $\lambda $ IS NOT a variable : The value of  $\lambda$ is imposed by the conditions of the exercise : $\lambda=-8$.

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed view this problem as presenting 3 equations with 4 variables.
However the assumption that you need as many equations as variables is false for several reasons.

Example 1: Find $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x^2 + y^2 = 0$

Here we have one equation with two variables, but it has still a unique solution: $x = y = 0$. **The setting where the "as many equations as variables" rule of thumb shines is when the equations are linear**.

Example 2: Find $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ not all $0$ such that  $x+y = 0$ and $x-y = 0$

Here we have two equations and two variables, but solving the equation system leads to $x=y=0$ which is not a valid solution. **The question is not to solve the system**, having a unique solution to the equation system can prevent having a solution to the question.

Example 3: Find $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ not all $0$ such that $x + y = 0$ and $x + \lambda y = 0$

Here we have two equation with 3 variables, but **the variables don't all have the same status**. If we choose one value for $\lambda$, then we have a *linear* system for *x* and *y*. We actually want to choose $\lambda$ so that the linear system won't have a unique solution, as it will be all $0$.

The third example is very close to your problem, if you can solve it you will be have a good understanding of it. I suggest you then look for the criteria for a unique solution if you are still stuck, and you should treat $\lambda$ as a constant of the linear system while calculating the criteria.